# pgf plot and foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

I have this function y=a*x^2 where a changes (-2.4,-2.1,-1.8,....,2.1,2.4) and i want to draw it with pgf plots. Problem is i dont know how to implement this i think i'll need foreach loop or something.
I've found a solution but it's not what i want because i have to enter 17 functions manually like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\begin{axis}[grid=major, xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-30, ymax=30, xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$y$];    
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan,]{-2.4*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{-2.1*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{-1.8*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{-1.5*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{-1.2*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{-0.9*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{-0.6*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{-0.3*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{0*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{0.3*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan,]{0.6*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{0.9*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan,]{1.2*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{1.5*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan,]{1.8*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{2.1*x^2};
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan,]{2.4*x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

To get graph

[image: graph]

I want to replace this 17 functions with one where a changes in interval (-2.4,...,2.4) but don't know how. I'm new to latex.

Answer (score 12):

Replace all the `\addplot` by

```
\foreach \a in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{\a*x^2};
}
\foreach \a in {-2.1,-1.5,...,2.4}{
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{\a*x^2};
}
```

**Code**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[grid=major, xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-30, ymax=30, xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$y$];
\foreach \a in {-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{\a*x^2};
}
\foreach \a in {-2.1,-1.5,...,2.4}{
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{\a*x^2};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Or with `\pgfplotsinvokeforach`, one can say `\begin{axis}[grid=major, xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-30, ymax=30, xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$y$];
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2.4,-1.8,...,2.4}{
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=cyan]{#1*x^2};
}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-2.1,-1.5,...,2.4}{
\addplot [domain=-5:5, samples=100, color=red,dashed]{#1*x^2};
}
\end{axis}`

Answer (score 10):

Another way, using a single `\foreach` and a user-defined `cycle list`. This `cycle list` can then be used throughout your document if desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{{color=cyan},{color=red,dashed}} % can now be used throughout the document

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=major, 
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, 
  ymin=-30, ymax=30, 
  xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$y$, 
  domain=-5:5, 
  samples=100,
  cycle list name=mylist
]
  \foreach \a in {-2.4,-2.1,...,2.4}{
    \addplot{\a*x^2};
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: As pointed out by Kpym in a comment, `\addplot` suffices since I moved `[domain=-5:5,samples=100]` into the main `axis` environment options. (This is good practice anyway; to save typing, you should let the plots inherit as many keys as possible and override locally as needed.) If you have any local keys set (that is, `\addplot[<local options>]`), you must use `\addplot+` for the `cycle list` to work properly within `\foreach`.

Comment: why you put `\addplot+` and not `\addplot` ?

Comment: @Kpym, good catch. It would be required for `cycle list`s to work with `\foreach`, but only if I had left `[domain=-5:5,samples=100]` in the options to `\addplot`. Now that I've moved those options to the `axis` environment, `\addplot+` is no longer required.

Answer (score 7):

Or with just one `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}    
\begin{axis}[grid=major, xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-30, ymax=30, xlabel=$t$, ylabel=$y$]
\foreach \Valor [count=\Cont] in {-2.4,-2.1,...,2.4} 
{
  \ifodd\Cont\relax
  \def\Color{cyan}
  \def\Shape{}
  \else
  \def\Color{red}
  \def\Shape{dashed}
  \fi
  \edef\temp{%   
    \noexpand\addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=100,color=\Color,\Shape]{\Valor*x^2};
  }
  \temp
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]