# Using pgffor to convert comma separated sequence to sequence of coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, strings

I have a comma separated sequence of pairs

```
\def\sequence{0/1, 1/3, 2/2, 3/2, 4/0, 5/3, 6/3, 7/3}
```

I would like to use `pgffor` to convert this into

```
{(0,1) (1,3) (2,2) (3,2) (4,0) (5,3) (6,3) (7,3)}
```

which I plan to use along with `\draw [smooth] plot coordinates` to make a smooth curve.

Is there any way of doing this simply?

If not, is there a simple way to emulate the functionality of `draw [smooth] plot coordinates` with just a `\foreach \i/\j in \sequence {...}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\sequence{ 0/1, 1/3, 2/2, 3/2, 4/0, 5/3, 6/3, 7/3}

\def\points{}
\foreach\x/\y in\sequence{%
  \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\mycoords\expandafter{\points (\x,\y)}%
}%

\draw [thick] plot [smooth] coordinates \points;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219592/pgf-plot-and-foreach-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following stores them in the coordinate format

```
\def\mycoords{}
\def\myseq{0/1,1/3,2/2,3/2,4/0,5/3,6/3,7/3}
\foreach\x/\y in\myseq{%
  \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\mycoords\expandafter{\mycoords (\x,\y)}%
}%
```

Comment: When attempting use `\draw [smooth] plot coordinates \mycoords`, I get an error "! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate."

Comment: @Hayden I get the desired results. Did you put a semicolon in the end? Otherwise it will keep looking

Comment: I've added an MWE to my question.  Maybe I missed something simple.

Comment: @Hayden You forgot to change one `\mycoords` to `\points`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Well I'll be damned.  It was something simple. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @percusse Henri noticed my issue, but I do still have a question.  When I had first tried to do the problem, I had done something remarkably close to what you did, but with `\edef` instead of `\xdef`.  What is it about `\xdef` that makes this work, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Hayden `\xdef` = `\global\edef`

Comment: @Hayden At each spin of the loop the code is run in a local scope and after each loop the variables go back to their previous state loosing the changes. To prevent that you need to declare things globally. So as Henri mentioned. There is also the nonexpanding couple which is `\def` and `\gdef`

Comment: @percusse & Henri thanks, that clarifies it a lot.  Thanks for the help!